# 10% fraud, while purchasing and selling. Whats the overall profit?

Tags: arithmetic, percentages

Ok, so the answer i find logical is $21$%. Like :

100 bucks paid, 110 items got. (10% profit).

Then, 110 items you sell at 10% profit, you get 121 items worth of bucks. So, 100 bucks investment, 121 bucks return. Profit 21%.

More Formally :

**$10$% fraud on purchase :** Buying 110 items for price of 100. Cost Price/item = $\frac{10}{11}$
 **$10$% fraud on sale :** Getting 110 bucks by selling 100 items. Thus, Selling Price/item = $\frac{11}{10}$

Thus, overall Profit Percentage :$$\frac{\frac{11}{10} - \frac{10}{11}}{\frac{10}{11}} * 100 = 21$$

The book says Profit Percentage is $22\frac{2}{9}$%

What am i doing wrong ?

Comment: First, why are you using the word "fraud"?  I see nothing here that would necessarily constitutes a crime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, So i guess this is how it goes :

Lets say 1 item cost 1 buck.

Thus, buy 100 items for 90 bucks (10% purchase fraud).
Now, sell 100 items for 110 bucks (10% sale fraud).

Total money in : 90 bucks.
Total money out : 110  bucks.

Profit Percentage = $\frac{110 - 90}{90}*100$ = $22\frac{2}{9}$

Comment: The numbers look good, but it seems like a strange use of the word, "fraud".

Comment: The question had it like this : the merchant was using a biased scale to his advantage.. thus, profits were fraudulent..